# Is it possible to scrape using javascript on website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, screen-scraping

I want to use web-scraping using javascript, but **not** outside of a browser, I mean I want to do it inside my website.

is it possible in some way?

and if it's not possible, if I want to do it using node.js ( like cheerio or request ), so is it possible to connect my website to the node.js that scraped the website?

I saw this code:

```
  const request = require('request');

  request('http://stackabuse.com', function(err, res, body) {  
      console.log(body);
  });
```

but how instead of printing it to console.log, I could print it to my html page?

Comment: It's easy with Electron framework https://electronjs.org/

Comment: Please check this https://en.jeffprod.com/blog/2019/web-scraping-with-electron/

Comment: It's easy in node.js but not possible in a modern browser for security reasons

Comment: @Paulpro so is there a way to extract the data from node.js back to the browser?

Comment: You could use Express to publish HTTP endpoint from node.js, you could use then this endpoint from your extension to process scrapped html.